# Restarting number sequence based on date

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am hoping someone can help. I am trying to create a referencing system that would create a UID which resets by day. The reference will follow a structure of users initials, todays date and whichever number has been logged that day. So for example

- "MB - 20211015 - 001"
- "MB - 20211015 - 002"
- "AD - 20211015 - 003"

The counter is what I want to reset every day so on the 16th it was reset to 001

- "MB - 20211016 - 001"
- "AD - 20211016 - 002"
- "EH - 20211016 - 003"

I have a code which can get the number but it does not work dynamically in conjunction with the date. Can someone please assist?

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim Nextnum As Long
Dim Ini as String

Ini = Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(Application.Username), ws1.range("IniLookup"), 4, 0)

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Lookups")
Nextnum = ws.Range("AB2").End(xlDown).Value + 1

Set ws2 = Worksheets("SMEXP")

With ws2
    .Range("B15") = Ini & " - " &Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd") & "- " & Nextnum
End With
```

Comment: Where from MB, AD, EH are taken? Or build, if this is the case. We need to understand the logic of its creation. The rest is easy to be accomplished. Is it that `Ini`?

Comment: Yes that is correct. The Ini is the MB, AD, EH etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next way:

```
.Range("B15").value = Ini & " - " & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & " - " & Format(NextNum, "000")
```

Being a `Long`, I suppose that `NextNum` is something like `3`, `4` and so on...

In order to reinitialize `NextNum` every day, you should replace

```
Nextnum = ws.Range("AB2").End(xlDown).Value + 1
```

with

```
If ws.Range("AC" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).Value = Date Then
        NextNum = ws.Range("AB2").End(xlDown).Value + 1
        ws.Range("AB2").End(xlDown).Offset(1).Value = NextNum
        ws.Range("AC" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Date
  Else
        NextNum = 1
        ws.Range("AB2").End(xlDown).Offset(1).Value = NextNum
        ws.Range("AC" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Date
  End If
```

Of course, the column AC:AC to be used if not used already. If not available, replace "AC" with any other available column. You should only place once the current date on that column, on its last row.

Comment: Thank you however, this would not reset back to 001 the next day looking at it?

Comment: @MBrann Of course, not. Did you ask about that and I missed it? Anyhow, I only transform the part of your code to deliver what you required, **based of the data you supply**. I mean, `Ini`, and the incremented `NextNum`. In order to solve this issue you should use another column where to place the current date. If the sequence is in "AB:AB" column, let us say "AC:AC". Then, when extract, in fact I will edit the answer and try suggesting something to do what you say (**now**) that is needed...

Comment: @MBrann Do you only like asking questions? A little feedback did not kill anybody...

Comment: apologies for the delay coming back. This has indeed worked. Many Thanks.

Comment: @MBrann When asking a question, it is good to check it a little more often... But glad I could (finally) Help!